# Программирование под WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Как правильно написать диалог которое приложение должно показывать юзеру для работы с любым сервером локальным, важно запомнить установки и далее не показывать.должен иметь три поля

1. имя сервера
2. имя базы
3. чекбокс: trusted connection
   буду признателен если покажите пример ;)

Comment: А проблема-то в чем? "Правильно" тут быть не может: вот как правильно хранить настройки - в реестре, в INI, в файле своего формата, на удаленном сервере в JSON (или десятке других форматов) или вообще в БД (тоже десяток вариантов)?

Comment: вам нужен диалог подключения к sql server'у?

Comment: @Stack да,что бы подключатся к базе из любого сервера где установлен та база для которого было написана программа,ну собственно этот диалог должен имитеровать строка подключения

Comment: понятно. можно использовать готовый, см. мой ответ ниже.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для подключения к sql server можно использовать готовый DataConnectionDialog -- входит в пакет [Microsoft Data Connection Dialog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog).
Примеры использования [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32326126/5673266) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6895428/5673266).

Как скачать пакет и извлечь из него сборки? -- [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475908/196972).

Comment: спасибо,здесь уже понятно что все будет работать как надо,но я в первые работаю пакетами Nuget,не могли бы сказать когда юзер будет вводить имя сервер и имя базы из формы с чем буду сравнять и  куда вставлять что бы работать сним в коде?

Comment: если в Visual Studio нет поддержки работы с nuget, то как скачать пакет -- добавил в ответ. в пакете находите сборку. и подключаете ее к проекту как обычно.